# How can I change data in my ejs file according to the information obtained from an API? (I would like to add conditionals.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

```
//weather.ejs
<div class="card" >
        <div class="UVradiation">
            <div class="title">
                <h2 class="uv">Current UV radiation: <%= uvdata %></h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <% if(uvdata === '0' || uvdata === '1' || uvdata === '2') { %>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac risus sed.</p>              
                <% } else if(uvdata === '3' || uvdata === '4' || uvdata === '5') { %>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac risus sed.</p>
                <% } else if(uvdata === '6' || uvdata === '7') { %>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac risus sed.</p>
                <% } else if(uvdata === '8' || uvdata === '9' || uvdata === '10') { %>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac risus sed.</p>
                <% } else { %>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac risus sed.</p>
                <% } %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I got `uvdata` from index.js file. Now I would like to change my paragraphs according to the number I got for `uvdata`. The code above is definitely not working, it's just for an idea. What do I do to get the desired output?

Comment: Assuming `uvdata` actually has those values that you compare it to (such as the string `'2'`), what you showed _is_ the correct solution. What is not working about it? (Other than that you can't see any change because all your paragraphs look the same) - One thing I could think of would be that maybe your `uvdata` is a number and not a string, yet you do a strict comparison (`===`) with a string and not a number.

Comment: You were right, uvdata was indeed a number, I overlooked it. Thankyou so much